# How to Update table using substr for blob?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, blob, substr

Update Query I tried:

```
 Update table_name
   set data='.....' || Dbms_lob.substr(data,1,20)
   where key  ='...'
```

It can be updated but all the data after position 20 was also cleared.

How do i modify the sql?

Comment: Please post your query,sample i/p,desired o/p

Comment: @user1557535: What exactly are you trying to achieve? And what kind of data is the *data* column supposed to contain?

Answer (score 2):

Check the syntax on dbms_lob.substr. It's the reverse of a standard substr, so if you want the first 20 characters from data, it'll be dbms_lob.substr(data,20,1). Or, better,

```
dbms_lob.substr(lob_loc=>data,amount=>20,offset=>1);
```

Note that it returns a varchar2, so the amount <= 32767.

Answer (score 0):

update [tableName] set field=dbms_lob.substr(field, 3,1)+'abc' where field=value

It cant work...